# How to control the number of records per run

Tags: trigger, schedulebatch, insert

I would like to know the best way for me to insert X amounts of records at a time.

**For example:**

Suppose I want to enter a list of 50000 records. In order not to run into problems, I thought of something asynchronous (just like batch) so that records are inserted later.

However, for the Batch to be run by "batches" as far as I know it needs to run a query and start the process.

I would like to make this same stream but without the need for a query inside it. Or if you have any other suggestions, I accept too.

Comment: I feel like it's a bit unclear exactly what your goal is. Where are these Accounts being sourced from? Are they being created in Apex? Inserted from a CSV file? Why do you need to enter them in sets of 600 instead of 200?

Comment: @Morgan Marchese 600 is just an example

Comment: The source of this information still isn't clear though. Are you asking how to configure a batch job to batch in sets higher than 200 when creating the batch job through Apex?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the details that Morgan mentions.

Comment: I edited my post @MorganMarchese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Batch Apex

Batch apex doesn't need to query using SOQL to process records in batches. Iterating over Database.QueryLocator is what you are referring to in that case.

However, we can also iterate over sObject Lists using batches as well.

**Take the following batch and execute anonymous for example:**

```
public class testBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
  public List<sObject> sObjectList;

  public testBatchClass(List<sObject> sObjects) {
    this.sObjectList = sObjects;
  }
  global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {
    return sObjectList; // changed
  }
  global void execute(
    Database.BatchableContext batchableContext,
    List<sobject> scope
  ) {
    System.debug('Hello World! ' + scope.size());
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext) {}
}
```

**With the following Execute Anonymous:**

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
for(Integer i = 0;i<2000;i++){
    Account acc = new Account();
    accountList.add(acc);
}
testBatchClass batch = new testBatchClass(accountList);
database.executeBatch(batch,600);
```

This will result in your Account List being processed in batches of 600, each time outputting a System debug showing 600 records in the list (with the last batch showing 200).

### Data Loader

If you are trying to insert records from a CSV, then something like Data Loader or an online Data Loader equivalent is your option. Data Loader has a maximum batch size of 10,000 if you change the settings to use the Bulk API, otherwise the limit is 200.

Comment: Thanks! It was this insert using batch that was in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert records in batches, Data Loader is the correct tool for the job. Once you install it, you can go into options and set the batch size from 200 to whatever you wish.